# Codeigniter: All pages shows 404 page not found (codeigniter's 404, not apache's)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Recently, before my PC changed hard disk, I was using Virtual Host.
After I changed hard disk, I am now using apache's htdocs folder.
When I tried accessing my codeigniter project again, all pages show '404 Page Not Found'.
It is not from my web server because I can tell the error message is from CodeIgniter's(because it is a styled 404 error page).

My Project has two controllers: (`Admin.php` and `Vendor.php`). These two were working just fine.

Things I tried:

- Checked my config/config.php

  ```
  $config['base_url'] = '';
  $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
  ```

  then I tried changing it to:

  ```
  $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Work%20Projects/Admin_Panel/';
  ```
- Tried accessing my controllers with and without the `index.php` in case my mod_rewrite is not functioning. Still not working.

  ```
  http://localhost/Work%20Projects/Admin_Panel/index.php/admin
  http://localhost/Work%20Projects/Admin_Panel/admin
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Change this

in **Config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

**.htacess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**NOTE**: In my pc also having same problem. But when i upload to server its working perfectly.

so till that You use with

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Work%20Projects/Admin_Panel/index.php/';
```

when you uploading just add a domain name and run this works perfectly.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
```

Comment: Okay thanks. I will try that later. It's working when I uploaded it though, but not working locally.

Comment: Actually, it was just an issue with my path inside web server, not CodeIgniter's. Sorry to bother you about this.